# Python Selenium - replacing the location['x'] value within an iteration followed by click()

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

in order to automize some tasks in the browser with Selenium I need to identify a certain field on a website and click it. Because the values I'm using to identify the correct field can be displayed multiple times I'm iterating through the findings including multiple conditions. Maybe the code is written ineffectivly, but the conditions - with the goal of locating the correct x and y coordinate is working. I'd like to know if I can somehow modify a location['x'] value in order the execute a click command.

```
        #  finding the X Value
        tempmatchesx = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[text()='" + tempoa + "']")
        tempmatchesxVal =''

        if indicator == '1':
            for i in tempmatchesx:
                if (i.location['x'] >= temptype['x']) and (i.location['y'] >= temptype['y']) and (i.location['x'] < temptypeoppo['x']):
                    tempmatchesxVal = i.location['x'] 
                    break
        elif indicator == '2':
            for i in tempmatchesx:
                if (i.location['x'] >= temptype['x']) and (i.location['y'] >= temptype['y']) and (i.location['x'] > temptypeoppo['x']):
                    tempmatchesxVal = i.location['x']  
                    break

        # finding the Y Value
        tempmatchesy = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[text()='" + tempgoals + "']")
        tempmatchesyVal =''

        if indicator == '1':
            for i in tempmatchesy:
                if (i.location['x'] >= temptype['x']) and (i.location['y'] >= temptype['y']) and (i.location['x'] < temptypeoppo['x']):
                    i.location['x'] = tempmatchesxVal
                    i.click()

                    break
        elif indicator == '2':
            for i in tempmatchesy:
                if (i.location['x'] >= temptype['x']) and (i.location['y'] >= temptype['y']) and (i.location['x'] > temptypeoppo['x']):
                    i.location['x'] = tempmatchesxVal
                    i.click()
```

So basically the part my question is referring to is the following:

`i.location['x'] = tempmatchesxVal
 i.click()`

Within an iteration, is it somehow possible to replace the location-X value with the before identified x value (tempmatchesxVal)? 
Or could the way I did it work and the failure (without error code) might be somewhere else?
For now, no item gets clicked.

***Update:***

The purpose of the whole is to click an element where I dont know now the content from, therefor I can't simply search for that. There I identifying the column and row where the element is lcoated.

Two "find_elements_by_xpath" are done with different inputs - the first is **tempoa** to identify column (x-value) and the second **tempgoals** for the row (y-value).

Apparently I can't modify an i.location[coordinate] - how can I then click that element?

Comment: You cannot set coordinate using Selenium, only with JavaScript. Can you share the URL or at least HTML in text format, and screenshot of the page with clearly explain your goals?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it on my own. Instead of going with the initial idea of modifying the coordinates (thanks to the answers - so thats not possible) I implemented an additional condition:

```
for i in tempOdds:
if (i.location['y'] == tempmatchesyVal) and (i.location['x'] >= tempmatchesxVal):
```

So basically only allowing elements with the same x and y coordinates/ x can be bigger but the first chosen one is the correct one

Answer (score 0):

It is not fully clear to me what are your conditions, and what some of the code's purpose it, but what seems very wrong is assigning new value to i.location[something].
`i` are html elements, you can get their location, but I don't think setting them is functioning.

Update: element's location is the location in pixels from the top left corner of the page. You mention columns and rows: if there is some kind of table on the page, I doubt i.location would work for you identifying the columns and rows you are looking for. If you like to work with pixel offsets, though, you can check `action_chains` for moving the mouse, and clicking. https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html

Comment: I need to do it twice because the element which is searched for differs. In the first its 'tempoa' and in the second its 'tempgoals'.
With that I have identified a certain column position as well as the needed row.
I dont know the content of the cell I'm looking for therefor no additional search possible. With know column and row I thought all needed is there, no it's only the problem of slecting (click) the element - coordinates are know: x Value of the first search and y value of the second.

Did that help to clarify?